# text in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Is there a way to write text in mathematica so you have something like x/f(x) without getting 1/f? writing Text[x/f(x)] doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
TraditionalForm[HoldForm[1/x]]
```

HoldForm makes sure if x or another variable is assigned that it will not be substituted.
Also try TextForm or one of the many other formatting forms:

InputForm
FullForm
StandardForm
...

Comment: It sounds like what bebe wants is TraditionalForm[x / f[x]]. 

Two issues overall bebe:

1. In Mathematica f(x) means Times[f, x], i.e. multiplication. That's why the x was canceling out to give 1 / f. You want f[x] which means the function f with the argument x.

2. To render x / f[x] in old fashioned mathematics notation (such as using round parentheses "()" instead of Mathematica's square brackets "[]") you use TraditionalForm:

TraditionalForm[x / f[x]]

HoldForm is also a good tip.